Call of Solidworks PDM API GetFileFromPath in a vbscript script
I'm writing a simple script to count the number of referenced files giving a file in a vault of Solidworks PDM.
I get a Type mismatch error in GetFileFromPath method which has the following declaration for VBA:
Visual Basic (Declaration)
Function GetFileFromPath( _
ByVal bsFilePath As System.String, _
Optional ByRef ppoRetParentFolder As IEdmFolder5 _
) As IEdmFile5
This is the script:
Dim vault
Set vault = CreateObject("ConisioLib.EdmVault")

vault.LoginAuto "VaultName", 0

If Not vault.IsLoggedIn Then
    WScript.Echo "Impossible to login."
Else
    Dim filePath
    filePath = "D:\Comp\Projects\XYZABC.sldprt.cvd"

    Dim file
    Dim rootFolder
    Set rootFolder = vault.RootFolder
    **Set file = vault.GetFileFromPath(filePath, rootFolder)**

    If Not file Is Nothing Then
        Dim referenceTree
        Set referenceTree = file.GetReferenceTree(0)
        Dim childPosition
        childPosition = referenceTree.GetFirstChildPosition("", 1, 1)
        Dim numReferencedFiles
        numReferencedFiles = 0

        While Not childPosition.IsNull
            numReferencedFiles = numReferencedFiles + 1
            referenceTree.GetNextChild childPosition
        Wend

        WScript.Echo "Number of files referenced to file " & filePath & ": " & numReferencedFiles
    Else
        WScript.Echo "File doesn't exist in vault."
    End If
End If

I tried to cast the filepath variable with CStr, but I got the same error

Your filename filePath = "D:\Comp\Projects\XYZABC.sldprt.cvd" is weird. That's not a SolidWorks file. Are you sure about that .cvd extension in the filename?

Yes, this is a virtual document that can be generated within SolidWorks PDM, specifically for referencing materials such as datasheets or scanned blueprints.

Well maybe, "this is a virtual document" is the answer to your problem, but I'm really not able to test it.

I get the same with a .sldasm file.
